# gettig error while add new tab in sale order view Wrong tab configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, blocks

i am trying to add new tab in `sale_order_view`. with follow xml but getting error after searching for hour for solution i could not succeeded to solve my problem.

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="sales_order_tabs">
            <action method="addTab"><name>test</name><block>test/adminhtml_test_edit_tab_itemform</block></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: so can you add the error?

Comment: `Wrong tab configuration` but i already find the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured out myself i was missing `implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface`

```
class SIE_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Test_Edit_Tab_Itemform extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
```